# "patch" rails render function to edit default options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I render :xml in rails I always want the :dasherize => false options. Is there a way to set it application wide as the default, without having to modify rails source code of course?

maybe a render function that somehow takes precedence over the first one and then calls it with this option...

Comment: hopefully it shouldn't break any other part of the application that uses the render function... it should work this way only when called by a controller (I think that's the only place it gets called from anyway..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing something like this does have the downside of potentially leading to unexpected behavior when someone else comes to look at your code (i.e. until they spot your overridden method they may wonder why it is behaving like dasherize false when that hasn't been explicitly specified.) That said, in ApplicationController or one of your specific controllers you can override the render method.

e.g. something like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
    options ||= {} # initialise to empty hash if no options specified
    options = options.merge(:dasherize => false) if options[:xml]
    super(options, extra_options, &block)
  end
end
```

If you want to allow dasherize to still be overridable in your calls to render you can do the Hash merge in the other direction e.g.

```
options = {:dasherize => false}.merge(options)
```

Comment: I ran into problems with this if I am rendering a page with the directive: render 'show.xml.builder', :layout => false.  options is then a String instead of a Hash.  I put in a check to make sure that it's a Hash, but it seems like a hack.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems reasonable to make the `if` condition into `if options.is_a? Hash and ooptions[:xml]` Alternatively, you could use a `begin`/`ensure` block with the `super` call in the `ensure`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try a sollution like this:

```
alias_method_chain :render, :no_dasherize

def render_with_no_dasherize(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
  new_options = options
  new_options = {:dasherize=>false}.merge(options) if(options[:xml])
  render_without_no_dasherize(new_options, extra_options, &block)
end
```

You can put it in Application Controller (so *all* controllers will be afected) or only in a specific controller.

Comment: This is a good practice since you may want to access the overriden function some time ;)