# Standarize JSON response in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services, api

I'm currently building an API using Rails. All the responses are in JSON.
As an example, my controllers use:

```
render json: @users, status: :ok
```

or, when I set `respond_to :json`, I use:

```
respond_with @users, status: :ok
```

I want to know what is the best way of standarizing my responses. Like:

```
{
  error_code: 0,
  content: ... (@users as JSON)
}
```

I've tried using JBuilder and also serializers (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), but I have to add the template to each view/serializer.

I want an **elegant way** of doing this so any controller that calls `render` or `respond_with` has the same template.

Comment: Why do you have to add a template to the serializer? Don't forget you can call `to_json` and the `as_json` method can be customized to remap or omit fields.

Comment: I don't actually need to add a template, I want to now what is the best way of standarizing the response regardless the gem I use (serializers, jbuilder, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but when I have to code these sorts of APIs, I simply define a method somewhere all my controllers can access it, and then always call render/redirect on that.

**Controller**

```
render json: formatted( @user, :ok )
```

**Method**

```
def formatted( obj, status )
  { error_code: status, content: obj }
end
```

Not necessarily "elegant," but it's readable, effective, easily maintainable, and will render properly however you want to output the results (plus it doesn't involve hacking on existing methods, which I tend to feel is sloppy).

Apologies if you were looking for something completely different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's one of the options I thought about and also the one I currently use.
I agree about the benefits your stated but I still believe there might be a more "rails-integrated" solution. So any output that gets generated by my controllers or any other gem, is also "formated".
What I actually try to accomplish is that my single-page app javascript will always get a message with the same format, regardless of an error or successful response.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. [There are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997061/override-render-json-in-no-model-object-rails-4) a few [questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194338/patch-rails-render-function-to-edit-default-options) on here along those lines, but I can't personally attest to their accuracy. Regardless, I hope you find a way to achieve your desired effect.